# Why do SSH keys work for users `root` & `freebsd` but not `postgres` (database owner)?

Tags: ssh, postgresql, freebsd, ssh-keys, digital-ocean

I have been using [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) running an a virtual machine at [DigitalOcean.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Ocean).

I use [Secure Shell (SSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) from my Mac to remote into a console session on the VM. I used [`ssh-keygen`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-keygen) to create the pair of encryption keys.

I deployed the public one copied to the FreeBSD SSH server. I did so via a back-door web-page supplied by Digital Ocean, pasting the text contents of the public key to a text field in a form.

That works well, logging me in for both `root` and `freebsd` users present by default on my new FreeBSD VM. When I connect via either the `root` or `freebsd` user accounts via ssh, **I am prompted to provide the passphrase protecting my local private key**.

```
ssh root@192.0.2.10
```

…or…

```
ssh freebsd@192.0.2.10
```

Then I installed the [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database system onto this FreeBSD server. As part of the scripts used to build and install Postgres, a third user account is added to the FreeBSD machine. By convention, the new account is named `postgres`. I gave that user a password using the `passwd` utility.

When I connect to the FreeBSD server as that user:

```
ssh postgres@192.0.2.10
```

…**I am prompted for that `postgres` user’s own password**. I am *not* prompted for the password protecting my local private encryption key.

➥ Why is the `postgres` user treated differently than `root` & `freebsd` with regard to using the public/private SSH keys to log me in?

FYI, I never touched any `authorized_keys` file on the remote SSH server (my FreeBSD VM).

My Question here may be a duplicate of [*Public SSH keys not working for all users on same server*](https://serverfault.com/q/296117/142214), I’m not sure.

Comment: Did you add your key to that users authorized keys file?

Comment: @Sven If you mean did I edit the `authorized_keys` file on the remote SSH server (my FreeBSD VM server), **I never did that for any** of the three users, not for `root` or `freebsd` (predefined when I spun up the new FreeBSD instance), and not for the newly-installed `postgres` user.

Comment: Then you either need to change your cloudinit script to also add that key to the freebsd user or to the script that installs Postgresql.

Comment: @Sven What key? I used `ssh-keygen` once, deployed the one public key to the SSH server once, and it worked for *both* `root` and `freebsd`. Why is a third added user treated differently?

Answer (score 1):

Add your public key to the postgresql users authorized keys file. This doesn’t happen during the init phase of your instance like with the root and freebsd user (cloud providers use scripts that do things like deploying ssh keys to a set of predefined users). This can be the same as the freebsd public key or you can use a different keypair for that purpose.

Comment: Are there multiple `authorized_keys` files on the SSH server machine? I only know of one: `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Using `cat` shows that it has my public SSH key, the key used to auto-login `root` and `freebsd` users, presumably. So the problem remains: Why is a newly created `postgres` user not auto-logged-in? Am I supposed to create another `authorized_keys` file somewhere else?